# How can I flip/rotate a PrintDocument in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, printing

I have a document that I want to be flipped / rotated 180 degrees when printed. (This is due to the orientation of label stock in the printer).

I think this property is influenced by the printer driver and therefore not 'settable'.

Is there a nice way i can rotate the print by 180 degrees without having to do anything too nasty?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accompilsh it with the following code

Note you need to do this before doing any of the Draw Functions

```
//flip the canvas then draw you document
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(180);
```